# postgresql/pgAdmin - accepting start_date & end_date arguments as input on query run

Tags: postgresql, subquery, declaration, sql-function

This is a postgresql db I'm working with using pgAdmin.

Forgive me if this is somewhat common knowledge, I'm new to postgresql in particular... and I didn't find any direct answers through prior searching.

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to implement start_time/end_time arguments as inputs when the query runs using pgadmin and any of it's built in features.

The data type I'm working with here is "timestamp with timezone".

Looking for some direction on the best way to implement this.

I considered declaring start_time and end_time as variables, then using WHERE to filter based on those, but without 3rd party/application level solutions, is there a way to prompt for input when the query runs inside of pgadmin?

I appreciate any suggestions- here's my attempt at getting something working, but it errors out: query has no destination for result data.

```
do $$
DECLARE
    start_date timestamp := '2020-10-1';
    end_date timestamp := '2020-10-5';
begin

select distinct on (account.id, menu.name, kitchen_item.name)
account.id as "Account ID",
account.firstname as "Seller First Name", 
account.lastname as "Seller Last Name",
account.email as "Seller Email",
account.phone as "Seller Phone",
address.address as "Seller Address (Street)",
address.address_2 as "Seller Address 2",
account.zip_code as "Seller Zip",
address.neighborhood as "Seller Neighborhood",
menu.name as "Name of active menu",
kitchen_item.name as "Dishes", 
kitchen_item.price as "Price",
kitchen_item.daily_max_orders as "Quantity",
menu.pickup_start_time as "Start time", 
menu.pickup_end_time as "End time",
menu.repeat_mon as "Monday",
menu.repeat_tues as "Tuesday",
menu.repeat_wed as "Wednesday",
menu.repeat_thurs as "Thursday",
menu.repeat_fri as "Friday",
menu.repeat_sat as "Saturday", 
menu.repeat_sun as "Sunday",
order_item.created as "Date of last sale"
from account
left join store on account.id = store.account_id
left join menu on store.id = menu.store_id
left join menu_item on menu.id = menu_item.menu_id
left join kitchen_item on (menu_item.kitchen_item_id = kitchen_item.id and store.id = kitchen_item.store_id)
left join orders on (orders.store_id = store.id)
left join order_item on (order_item.order_id = orders.id)
join store_address on store.id = store_address.store_id
join address on store_address.address_id = address.id
where orders.placed BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
order by account.id asc, menu.name, kitchen_item.name asc, order_item.created desc;

end $$;
```

Comment: IMO forget about pgAdmin4 - it is garbage. I don't like JAVA at all but dBeaver could be the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

`DO` creates an anonymous function that returns no data.
You can use `WITH`:

```
WITH input (start_date, end_date) AS 
(SELECT '2020-10-01'::timestamp AS start_date,
'2020-10-05'::timestamp AS end_date)
SELECT ...
FROM...
JOIN input 
WHERE orders.placed BETWEEN input.start_date AND input.end_date
```